# elasticsearch false or missing query

Tags: elasticsearch, coffeescript

How do I combine the OR so that I can query for a field that's either false or missing?

The documentation mentions using must_not. This does not work:

```
query = bool: must: [
  { 'bool':
    'or': [
      { 'term': 'badField': false }
      { 'term': 'badField': '' }
      { 'must_not': 'exists': 'field': 'badField' }
    ]
    should: [
      { 'term': 'goodField': true }
    ] }
]
```

Comment: What language is this query written in?

Comment: @Val oh it's coffeescript sorry.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Val pointed out, it looks like your query is a combination of query DSL and pseudo code. A proper query for your use case would be something along the lines of:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "goodField": {
              "value": true
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "must": [
        {
          "bool": {
            "should": [
              {
                "bool": {
                  "must_not": [
                    {
                      "exists": {
                        "field": "badField"
                      }
                    }
                  ]
                }
              },
              {
                "term": {
                  "badField": {
                    "value": false
                  }
                }
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I decided that I hate elasticsearch. It's clumsy and lacking in power.